# Inconsistent author name appearing for some authors while writing thesis

Tags: cross-referencing, citing, natbib, jabref, bibitem

I am using "Harvard" style while writing my thesis. While citing papers of more than 3 authors, in some cases lastNameAuthor1, LastNameAuthor2, LastNameAuthor3, LastnameAuthor4, and so on.. is appearing instead of lastNameAuthor1 et al.

This is happening in some cases only.

I searched every possible thing available but this could not get corrected. Please help me to correct this inconsistent behavior of BibTex. I am attaching a sample of the code.

```
\documentclass{iitkgpthesis}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{longtable}
%\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{longtable} 
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{N}{@{}m{0pt}@{}}

\newcommand{\SymbolInRed}{$\textcolor{red}{\times}$}
\renewcommand\chaptername{\bf CHAPTER}
\newcommand{\ssubsection}[1]{%
\subsection[#1]{\raggedright\normalfont\itshape\bfseries #1}}
\begin{document}

% Frontmatter. Add other pages as needed.
%\pagenumbering{roman}
%\include{firstpage}
%\include{frontmatter}
% \include{abstract} 
% \cleardoublepage
% \tableofcontents
% \cleardoublepage
% \listoftables
% \listoffigures
%\cleardoublepage
%\include{listofnotation}
%\cleardoublepage

\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RE]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[LO]{\rightmark}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
% Main thesis section
\pagenumbering{arabic}
%\input{test}

\cite{mahanthesh2017marangoni}, \cite{li2021dynamics}, \cite{khan2021transportation},\cite{algehyne2022cattaneo}, \cite{bai2022unsteady}, \cite{algehyne2022analysis}.\cite{kumar2020simultaneous}, \cite{li2021motion}.  \cite{khan2021marangoni}, \cite{khan2020numerical}, \cite{kumar2020heat}, \cite{tripathi2015dynamics},\cite{kumar2020wetting}, \cite{tripathi2015non}

\singlespacing
\bibliographystyle{harvard}
\bibliography{myref}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\cleardoublepage

\end{document}
```

These are some citations were output is like
[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436/184389) Please edit your question by adding a small compilable code containing only what's necessary to reproduce the behavior you're experiencing so that people are able to help you.

Comment: Some styles try to avoid compressing different lists of authors to the same "Name et al.". In that case those styles will show more author names than usual in order to make things unambiguous. We can only tell you whether that is the case here and if and how it can be turned off, if you show us a small example document that we can compile and that reproduces the output you are getting.

Comment: There is no single or unique "Harvard" style. Please tell us which bibliography style you employ and which citation management package, if any, you use.  If you use a package such as `natbib`, please also tell us which options you specify.

Comment: I have provided the code. Please let me know in case you need more details